# Using #if in SXA variant NVelocity template

Tags: sxa, nvelocity

I created a variant in SXA with a NVelocit template. In this variant I am displaying some text in an a tag: `<a href="$item.Fields.Link" target="_blank">Test</a>`

This works fine, but when my field "Link" is empty I don't want to show anything. So I found some information on NVelocity (not related to Sitecore though) that showed I could do this:

```
#if ($item.Fields.Link != "")
   <a href="$item.Fields.Link" target="_blank">Test</a>
#end
```

I also tried with single quotes, with `.empty`, .. but nothing seems to work. I get no output anymore when doing this. If I put something after my end (just to test), that text is still shown. My field is very empty (no space or so).

Is there a way to use some NVelocity coding in SXA?

ps: I found this blog from Michael https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2018/02/access-reference-fields-in-sxa.html where he uses `#set` so I guess something should be possible...

Using SXA 1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Dawid for telling me it was possible - it kept me searching for the solution. After a while I found out that I was comparing an object to a string.. In the output the string cast is done automatically but not for the comparison.
So I ended up with a working template like this:

```
#set ($url = $item.Fields.Link.ToString())
#if ($url != "")
  <a href="$url" target="_blank">Test</a>
#end
```

The trick was the `ToString()`..

Answer (score 3):

Something like this works for sure as I just checked on one of my old instances:

```
#if ($geospatial.Distance)
    <span style="color: red">$geospatial.Distance km<span>
#else
    <span style="color: brown">Nothing here<span>
#end
```

When there will be results which don't have a `$geospatial` in the context the if statement will work.

SXA is not adding any custom logic to those templates, we just run `Velocity.Evaluate`. So maybe Sitecore have some limitation on evaluating these templates.

There is another way to achieve what you want. You can add a custom processor to `ResolveVariantTokens` pipeline and implement your logic in a token (C# code).

[image]