# How to read a field in the variant template?

Tags: sxa

The requirement is to return the item id in the query string on button click. 
I added a template in the rendering variant and added the following line

```
<a href="https://some url?itemid=$item.ID">Button text</a>
```

Now, I want button text to come from the sitecore field. $item.fieldName is not working. What is the right way of reading the text from the sitecore field in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I am in doubt now that Dawid says it doesn't exist ootb, but I have something like this working:

```
$item.Fields.BookLink.ToString()
```

where "BookLink" is the name of my field. Hopefully your field does not have a space in the  name ;)

The "ToString" was needed in our case as we wanted to check if it was empty (see [Using #if in SXA variant NVelocity template](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/12371/237)).

Comment: Yep, this will work!

Comment: Thanks . @Gatogordo Can you please tell me how to read the link of the current item in the same case.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the method that @Gatogordo suggested you can use this method if your field has spaces in the name:

```
$item.Fields.get_Item("A Field With Spaces")
```

You can add `.ToString()` in the same way as it is used in the other answer.